# Creating an HTML link that will not be URL decoded

Tags: html, url, url-encoding

I need to create a link to a web page that contains the character `#` (`%23`). However, when the URL gets decoded (resulting in a URL containing `#`), the character is not recognized and the page is not displayed properly.

When I create a link as follows, the `%23` just gets replaced with `#`. This may be the behaviour of the browser, but how can I stop it and reach the proper URL with the string still URL encoded? I would prefer to do it without JavaScript if it is possible.

```
<a href="http://aWebsite.com/somePath/somePage %23myParameter">click</a>
```

Browser goes to: `http://aWebsite.com/somePath/somePage #myParameter`
I want to go to: `http://aWebsite.com/somePath/somePage %23myParameter`

Comment: Try adding `charset="UTF-8"`. Might Work. Probably not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to encode it a second time.  The "%" will become "%25" so you'll have:

```
<a href="http://aWebsite.com/somePath/somePage %2523myParameter">click</a>
```

**Edit:**
If you want the "#" to be sent to the server as part of the URL, then it's not going to work.  The browser treats that as a bookmark so it is removed from the requested URL.  Once the page is loaded, the browser will scroll to that bookmark.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did not think of that. However, the URL has to contain exactly `%23`; the resulting URL in this case will contains `%2523`, which is parsed as `%23` by the page. Instead the URL should contains exactly `%23`, then parsed by the page as `#`. The rest of the URL can be encoded or not, it does not seem to matter. I will update the question accordingly, as this is a pretty specific situation, sorry about that.

Comment: @Demat, are you expecting the "#" to be sent to the server as part of the requested URL?

Comment: After doing some testing, it seems the HTML renderer/browser that I am using is at fault. Clicking the link in Firefox works properly. In my situation, simply using `%23` (instead of `#`) in the `<a>` tag was sufficient to reach the page I needed. Since the real problem is not related to the question, I will generalize the question and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to doube encode it:

```
http://example.com/somePath/somePage %2523myParameter
```

`%25` will resolve in `%` in the final url